# Display file name from input type file - console.log(fileName) return null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display file name from input type file.

This is my code:

```
<input id="id_file_field" name="file_field" type="file" style="display:none" />
```

Here **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upload_file").click(function () {
        $("#id_file_field").trigger('click');
        var path = $("#id_file_field").val();
        var fileName = path.match(/[^\/\\]+$/);
        console.log(fileName);
    });
});
```

Why `console.log(fileName)` return `null`?

Comment: you need to wait for the change event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for the change event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upload_file").click(function () {
        $("#id_file_field").trigger('click');
    });
    $('#id_file_field').change(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        var fileName = typeof value == 'string' ? value.match(/[^\/\\]+$/)[0] : value[0]
        console.log(fileName);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8wcfv/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following js;

```
$("#upload_file").click(function () {
        $("#id_file_field").trigger('click');
    });

    $('#id_file_field').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var name = value.split(/[\\/]/);
        console.log(name[name.length - 1]);
    });
```

Here is a working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/BKuLT/3/**